# Issue when installing sqlite3 in node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Does anyone know how to fix this issue when running the command "npm install -g triplie"? I also get the same error when installing sqlite3 only.

This is node.js compiled manually, as I can't find a version in apt-get to install.

```
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:999:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1071:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.15.3-x86_64-linode44
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--name=sqlite3" "--configuration=Release" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--version=2.2.4" "--major=2" "--minor=2" "--patch=4" "--runtime=node" "--node_abi=node-v14" "--platform=linux" "--target_platform=linux" "--arch=x64" "--target_arch=x64" "--module_main=./lib/sqlite3" "--host=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/triplie/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v14-linux-x64" "--remote_path=./Release/" "--package_name=node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz" "--staged_tarball=build/stage/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz" "--hosted_path=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/" "--hosted_tarball=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/triplie/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.14-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node rebuild --name=sqlite3 --configuration=Release --module_name=node_sqlite3 --version=2.2.4 --major=2 --minor=2 --patch=4 --runtime=node --node_abi=node-v14 --platform=linux --target_platform=linux --arch=x64 --target_arch=x64 --module_main=./lib/sqlite3 --host=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/ --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/triplie/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v14-linux-x64 --remote_path=./Release/ --package_name=node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz --staged_tarball=build/stage/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz --hosted_path=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/ --hosted_tarball=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/triplie/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:76:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:999:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1071:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.15.3-x86_64-linode44
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/triplie/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/triplie/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.14-pre
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.5.19
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node rebuild --name=sqlite3 --configuration=Release --module_name=node_sqlite3 --version=2.2.4 --major=2 --minor=2 --patch=4 --runtime=node --node_abi=node-v14 --platform=linux --target_platform=linux --arch=x64 --target_arch=x64 --module_main=./lib/sqlite3 --host=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/ --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/triplie/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v14-linux-x64 --remote_path=./Release/ --package_name=node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz --staged_tarball=build/stage/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz --hosted_path=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/ --hosted_tarball=https://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.2.4-node-v14-linux-x64.tar.gz' (1)
npm ERR! sqlite3@2.2.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@2.2.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.15.3-x86_64-linode44
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "triplie"
npm ERR! cwd /root/node
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.14-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/node/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Perhaps it's due to your node version being from an unstable branch. Try with node v0.10.29 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error trying to install sqlite through npm for etherpad-lite. I checked out the 0.12 branch and rebuilt, and `npm install sqlite3` ran with no errors. My etherpad is now using an sqlite database, hooray!